# How to make complicated designs like bottom tab bar in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I want to make a tabbar like below in the application. How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make separation of whole design like below.

1. take normal icons for 3 buttons.
2. take normal view and align it to
   bottom, you can create component for it
3. in component, you create tab bar design by
   taking **background image which contain curve design** and **home icon required whole rounded icon**, just simply put them in view with TouchableOpacity which contains image. That's it !!

Comment: Congrats on your 1K rep :D, also, nice answer.